# Delphi 'Output unit dependency information' - what does it do?

Tags: delphi

There is an option in the Delphi compiler - 'Output unit dependency information' - I am unsure as to what this does, as although it seems to try and set the --depends option when the application is compiled, there is no extra output.

Does anyone know that is actually does?

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me that people ask questions like this rather than reading the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiling

Comment: On that very dialog there is a <help> button. If you press it, it will take you straight to the relevant help topic.

Answer (score 2):

Autodependency information embeds a list of all the .cpp file's
recursively #included headers and their timestamps into the .obj. That
information is used by the build system to rebuild the .obj if any of
the #included headers change.

Note that the option is "DISABLE autodependency information" - we
always include it by default. If it's turned off, .objs will not
contain the information and won't be automatically rebuilt when their
headers change.

from http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.ide/200809/0809301085.html

Further reference can be found on [Compiling](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Compiling) section of the Embarcadero documentation